# How to send GET request to API

Tags: django, api, web-applications

Summary: I have a job board, a user searches a zip code and all the jobs matching that zip code are displayed, I am trying to add a feature that lets you see jobs within a certain mile radius of that zip code. There is a web API ( www.zipcodeapi.com ) that does these calculations and returns zip codes within the specified radius, I am just unsure how to use it.

Using www.zipcodeapi.com , you enter a zip code and a distance and it returns all zip codes within this distance. The format for API request is as follows: `https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/<api_key>/radius.<format>/<zip_code>/<distance>/<units>`, so if a user enters zip code '10566' and a distance of 5 miles, the format would be `https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/<api_key>/radius.json/10566/5/miles` and this would return:

```
{
    "zip_codes": [
        {
            "zip_code": "10521",
            "distance": 4.998,
            "city": "Croton On Hudson",
            "state": "NY"
        },
        {
            "zip_code": "10548",
            "distance": 3.137,
            "city": "Montrose",
            "state": "NY"
        }
        #etc...
    ]
}
```

My question is how do I send a GET request to the API using django? 
I have the user searched zip code stored in         `zip = request.GET.get('zip')` and the mile radius stored in `mile_radius = request.GET['mile_radius']`. How can I incorporate those two values in their respective spots in `https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/<api_key>/radius.<format>/<zip_code>/<distance>/<units>` and send the request? Can this be done with Django or do I have this all confused? Does it need to be done with a frontend language? I have tried to search this on google but only find this for RESTful APIS, and I dont think this is what I am looking for. Thanks in advance for any help, if you couldn't tell i've never worked with a web API before.

Comment: Okay I will, thanks. I always thought that this was a way to create an API for your applications data, not to use another web API, but I will look into it!

Comment: It is both. But you must still specify the URL pattern and connect it to the REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package, to do exactly what you want. It's pretty straightforward and has good documentation.
Here's an example of how you could perform it for your case:

```
zip_code = request.GET.get('zip')
mile_radius = request.GET['mile_radius']
api_key = YOUR_API_KEY
fmt = 'json'
units = 'miles'
response = requests.get(
    url=f'https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/{api_key}/radius.{fmt}/{zip_code}/{mile_radius}/{units}')
zip_codes = response.json().get('zip_codes')
```

`zip_codes` should then be an array with those dicts as in your example.